# I am trying to use swift to invoke another application passing a file with no joy

Tags: ios, swift, invoke, uiapplication, openurl

I am trying to invoke an external application such as Numbers (.numbers) or Safari (.htm).  I have tested this with an internet URL and this works (with slight changes to the code here).  I tried to use a htm to invoke Safari local access but no joy.  canOpenURL returns true  Resp var) however openURL returns false (Resp2). 
I am not fixed to this code if there is some other way to do this or are there some restrictions with swift and the iOS simulator?

```
    var txtPath = NSString(string:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ReadMe", ofType: "htm")!)
    let targetURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: txtPath)
    let application=UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    var Resp=application.canOpenURL(targetURL!)
    var Resp2=application.openURL(targetURL!);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to launch the file URL to your ReadMe.htm file? You need to call `openURL` with a URL representing another app.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to invoke an external application

On iOS, the way to hand a document to another application is to use UIDocumentInteractionController and let the user pick an application. For example, if you start with a Numbers document, the user will be able to pick Numbers from the UIDocumentInteractionController (if it is present on the device).

Comment: More discussion in my book, here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_handing_off_a_document

Comment: Thanks the book explains this really well